# Jquery ui dialog box set position accross all pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, position

How can I set the positioning of jquery dialog box to be applied to all dialog calls instead of stating position:

```
{my: "center", at: "center", of: foo}
```

in every instance?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any OOTB solution, but you can wrap your dialog creation in a function:

```
function myDialog(selector, target) {
  return $(selector).dialog("widget").position({
    my: 'center',
    at: 'center',
    of: target
  });
}
```

And then create it with `myDialog("#dialog", foo)`. You might also want to make this be a simple [jQuery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) to avoid global function declaration.

Comment: Thank you. Please bear with me.. Not only will I have to call the new function on every page but also call myDialog("#dialog", foo) in every instance of jquery dialog call.

Comment: Can you please update your question and give an example source code that would show exactly what you are trying to get rid of?

Comment: Hi again. Jquery dialog box is positioned at the center of "window" by default. I  change it's position every time I call the widget as follows;
{ $(function(){
    $( "#dialog-xxx" ).dialog({
 modal:true,
 position: {my:"center",at:"center",of:foo},
 buttons:{OK: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");}} }); });

I was wondering if there is a way to set positioning to "foo" without having to repeat it in every dialog call instance and changing jquery code.